# My bot is not checking for conditions and only taking input again and again

Tags: python

Hey guys i tried to create a bot who takes input by voice and do some sort of things according to the input but It is not checking for the conditions and only taking input I don't know why this is happening
I used chatterbot for the conversation to make it efficient and some sort of details to open softwares or any website which i want to open Here is the code:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from time import sleep
import logging
from gtts import gTTS
from playsound import playsound
import os
import speech_recognition as sr
import datetime
import webbrowser
import requests
import json
import keyboard as kb


def speak(toSpeak):
    tts = gTTS(text=toSpeak, lang='en')
    tts.save('voice.mp3')
    playsound('voice.mp3')
    os.remove('voice.mp3')


def take_usrInput():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        print("Listening...")
        # r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
        print("Recognizing...")
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
    return query
    


def wishMe():
    hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)
    if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:
        print("Chiya:Good Morning")
        speak("Good Morning!")

    elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:
        print("Chiya:Good Afternoon")
        speak("Good Afternoon!")

    else:
        print("Chiya:Good Evening")
        speak("Good Evening!")


def Kelvin_to_Celsius(K):
    return (K - 273.15)


def weather_details(city):
    api_key = "3fdb491821d893c2754b6a92458f7565"
    base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
    city_name = city
    complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name
    response = requests.post(complete_url)
    x = response.json()
    if x["cod"] != "404":
        y = x["main"]
        current_temperature = y["temp"]
        current_pressure = y["pressure"]
        current_humidity = y["humidity"]
        z = x["weather"]
        weather_description = z[0]["description"]
        print(" Temperature (in Celsius unit) = " +
              str(Kelvin_to_Celsius(current_temperature)) +
              "\n atmospheric pressure (in hPa unit) = " +
              str(current_pressure) +
              "\n humidity (in percentage) = " +
              str(current_humidity) +
              "\n description = " +
              str(weather_description))
    else:
        speak("City Not Found")
        print(" City Not Found ")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bot = ChatBot(
        "Chiya",
        read_only=False,
        storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
        logic_adapters=[
            'chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation',
            {
                "import_path": "chatterbot.logic.BestMatch"
            }
        ],
        preprocessors=[
            'chatterbot.preprocessors.clean_whitespace',
            'chatterbot.preprocessors.unescape_html',
            'chatterbot.preprocessors.convert_to_ascii'

        ],
        database_url='sqlite://database.sqlite3',
    )

    conversation = [
        "Hello",
        "Hi there!",
        "How are you doing?",
        "I'm doing great.",
        "That is good to hear",
        "Thank you.",
        "You're welcome.",
        "Yes, I am a girl"
    ]

    bot.set_trainer(ChatterBotCorpusTrainer)
    bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
    bot.train(conversation)
    bot.train('chatterbot.corpus.english')

    name = "Bs"
    wishMe()
    while True:
        # request = take_usrInput()
            request = str(take_usrInput()).lower()
            print(request)
            if 'Search on google' in request:
                speak("Searching on google...")
                print("Searching on google...")
                query = request.replace("Search on google", "")
                base_url = "https://www.google.com/search?q="
                final_url = base_url + query.replace(" ", "%20")
                webbrowser.open_new(final_url)

            elif "open youtube" in request:
                webbrowser.open("youtube.com")
            elif 'open google' in request:
                webbrowser.open("google.com")
            elif 'open stackoverflow' in request:
                webbrowser.open("stackoverflow.com")
            elif 'open insta' or 'open instagram' in request:
                webbrowser.open("instagram.com")
            elif 'open code' in request:
                codePath = "C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\Code.exe"
                os.startfile(codePath)
            elif 'time' in request:
                strTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                speak(f"Sir, the time is {strTime}")
            elif 'weather' in request:
                speak("Tell me the name of the city")
                print("Tell me the name of the city")
                city_name = take_usrInput()
                speak(f"Here is the weather details of {city_name}")
                weather_details(city_name)
            elif 'stop' or 'pause' in request:
                input('Press the enter to start...')
                if(kb.is_pressed('Enter')):
                    pass
            elif 'bye' or 'Bye' in request:
                exit()
            else:
                response = bot.get_response(request)
                print('Chiya:', response)
                speak(str(response))
```

if any one knows why it is occuring then plz help me

Comment: You'll need to provide some extra detail about where the program is getting to. Try adding some `print` statements to show the values of variables as your program runs.

Comment: Punctuation in prose is important!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add elif in second expression after the first one in open YouTube request

Comment: Please provide details of what this `elif` condition should be

Comment: In while loop where you are taking request as input you should use elif instead of if in case when request is open YouTube

Comment: Thanks for your reply I tried but doesn't solved the problem:(